# I want to disable click events on a list of buttons whilst they are animating

Tags: jquery, animation

I have tried various methods on doing this, but I cannot seem to stop a list of buttons from adding the class "inview" whilst an animation is going on.

I have a menu that slides up, then down.

On the downward animation, if I click another button at just the right time, I will have two elements with the class "inview".

There should only be on element with class inview.

The "right time" would be when, I've clicked once, try a different button, but then press another one before the downward animation has finished.

This leaves me with two elements that have display block (class "inview"), instead of the one.

I have [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/6LLsnsp4/) demonstrating the problem so you can recreate it yourself.

But here's the offending function:

```
function menu_actions() {
    // get class defined with menu_classes function
    var getClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    //
    if ($('div', '.details').hasClass('inview') && $(this).hasClass('click')) {
        console.log('inview and click');
        $('.btn', '#feature-nav').off('click', menu_actions);
        // bleach .details classes 
        $('.inview', '.details').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('inview');
        });
        // animation
        details.slideUp('slow');
        dropmenu.slideUp('medium');
        setTimeout(function () {
            // move content body up
            mainBody.addClass('moveBody');
            $('.btn', '#feature-nav').on('click', menu_actions);
        }, 100);
    } else if (!$('div', '.details').hasClass('inview') && $(this).hasClass('click')) {
        console.log('not inview but click');
        $('.btn', '#feature-nav').off('click', menu_actions);
        // move content body back down
        mainBody.removeClass('moveBody');
        // give specific element class
        // give this one some "pop"
        $('.' + getClass, '.details').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $(this).addClass('inview');
        });
        // animate
        details.slideDown('slow');
        dropmenu.slideDown('medium', function () {
            $('.btn', '#feature-nav').on('click', menu_actions);
        });
    } else if ($('div', '.details').hasClass('inview') && !$(this).hasClass('click')) {
        console.log('inview but not click');
        $('.btn', '#feature-nav').off('click', menu_actions);
        // bleach all classes, add class to specific button
        // give this one some "pop"
        $('.inview', '.details').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.inview', '.details').removeClass('inview');
        });
        $('.btn', '#feature-nav').removeClass('click');
        $(this).addClass('click');
        // animate
        details.slideUp('slow');
        dropmenu.slideUp('medium');
        //
        setTimeout(function () {
            mainBody.addClass('moveBody');
        }, 100);
        // timed animation for smoother transitions
        setTimeout(function () {
            // move content body back down
            mainBody.removeClass('moveBody');
            // give this one some "pop"
            $('.' + getClass, '.details').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).addClass('inview');
            });
            //
            details.slideDown('slow');
            dropmenu.slideDown('medium', function () {
                $('.btn', '#feature-nav').on('click', menu_actions);
            });
        }, 900);
    } else if (!$('div', '.details').hasClass('inview') && !$(this).hasClass('click')) {
        console.log('not inview and not click');
        $('.btn', '#feature-nav').off('click', menu_actions);
        // bleach all classes, add class to specific button AND .details
        $('.btn', '#feature-nav').removeClass('click');
        $('.inview', '.details').removeClass('inview');
        $(this).addClass('click');
        // move content body up
        mainBody.removeClass('moveBody');
        // give specific element class
        // give this one some "pop"
        $('.' + getClass, '.details').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $(this).addClass('inview');
        });
        // animate 
        details.slideDown('slow');
        dropmenu.slideDown('medium', function () {
            $('.btn', '#feature-nav').on('click', menu_actions);
        });
    }
} // end of menu actions
```

My current method was to use the `on()/off()` jquery functions to try and disable the buttons.

I should clarify that this problem only appears to occur on the downward animation, when this condition is met:

```
 } else if ($('div', '.details').hasClass('inview') && !$(this).hasClass('click')) {
```

Or simplified as condition "menu is 'inview' but button does not have class 'click'".

Please try the jsfiddle, but it's a little difficult to replicate.

Comment: Why all the multi-selectors? What is the significance of selecting all divs and elements with class `details`?

Comment: @Tomanow I'm using them to check if any divs have the class "inview" and removing them and specifically add it one element.